# How to calculate the expectation of the exponetial of stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, expectation

Let X be stochastic process defined by $X_t = exp(\sigma W_t)$, where W is a Wiener process and  $\sigma$ is a constant. Then we have

$$E(X_T)=E(e^{\sigma W_T})=\exp(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 T)$$.

I know this is the correct result but I don't know how to get this?

Comment: By the very definition of a Wiener process, $W_T$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $T$. For any Gaussian random variable the exponential moments can be calculated explicitly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions

Comment: @saz Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $E(W_T)=0$ and $E(g(W_t))=\int_\mathbb{R}g(w)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2T\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2T}{w^2}}dw$.

$g(x)=e^{\sigma x} $

And finally we get:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2T\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\sigma w}e^{-\frac{w^2}{2T}}dw =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2T\pi}}\int e^{-\frac{w^2-2T\sigma w +T^2\sigma^2}{2T}}e^{\frac{T^2\sigma^2}{2T}}dw=e^{\frac{T\sigma^2}{2}}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2T\pi}}e^{-\frac{w^2-2T\sigma w +T^2\sigma^2}{2T}}dw$$

$$E(e^{\sigma W_T})=e^{\frac{T\sigma^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_t = \exp \left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t \right) X_t = \exp \left( \sigma W_t - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}t \right)$. Ito's lemma yields 
$$ dY_t = \left( \sigma Y_t dW_t  - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} Y_t dt \right) + \frac 12 \cdot \sigma^2 dt = \sigma Y_t dW_t, $$
hence $Y_t$ is a martingale. It follows that 
$$ \exp \left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t \right) \mathbb{E} X_t = \mathbb{E} Y_t = \mathbb{E} Y_0 = \mathbb{E} 1 = 1. $$